# How to create an executable file from React-Electron project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, electron, executable

I have a web app created with React. I want to create the desktop version of that app. To do that, i added `electron.js` file in the `public` folder. Inside the `electron.js` file is the basic electron code that take `index.html` and turn it to a desktop app that looked like this:

```
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require('electron')
const path = require("path");
const isDev = require("electron-is-dev");

function createWindow () {
    const win = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 800,
        height: 600,
        webPreferences: {
            nodeIntegration: true
        }
    })

    win.loadURL(isDev ? "http://localhost:3000" : `file://${path.join(__dirname, "../build/index.html")}`);
}

app.whenReady().then(createWindow)

app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
    if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
        app.quit()
    }
})

app.on('activate', () => {
    if (BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) {
        createWindow()
    }
})
```

The app is works and I don't add any electron code to the `src` folder. How can i get the executable for Windows, Mac, and Linux in my React-Electron code? My machine run on linux

Comment: Read here https://www.electron.build/ Windows/Mac/Linux

Answer (score 2):

You could use a library called [electron-builder](https://www.electron.build/).

Install the library with npm install or yarn add then add a new task to package.json to run `electron-builder` for example to build an app to windows, linux and mac you can run, these can be put in package.json as well so you don't need to type it everytime you want to build. It's also possible to build an app using a programmatic API. You'll find more details in the docs, there are also [tutorials](https://www.electron.build/tutorials/loading-app-dependencies-manually) and [guides](https://www.electron.build/icons).

`electron-builder -mwl`